# Yii2 не выводит ошибки при валидации

Tags: php, yii2

Суть в том , что на странице есть несколько форм, созданных виджетом `Activeform` :

```
<div class="settings-line">
   <p class="ettings-label">Логин</p>
   <p class="settings-data"><?= $model->username; ?></p>
      <a  class="edit-settings">Редактировать</a>
         <div class="sett-drop">
          <?php
             $form = ActiveForm::begin([
             'options' =>
                [
                 'id' => 'change-username-form',
                 'class' => 'ng-pristine ng-valid',
                ]
              ]
              )
              ?>
 <div class="form-row">
   <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['class' => 't-inp'])->label('Логин'); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="form-row">
   <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Изменить'), ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-save']) ?>
 </div>
 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>         
</div>
</div> 

<div class="settings-line">
  <p class="settings-label">E-mail</p>
  <p class="settings-data"><?= $model->email; ?></p>
  <a class="edit-settings">Редактировать</a>
  <div class="sett-drop">
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
       'options' =>
       [
       'id' => 'change-username-form',
       'class' => 'ng-pristine ng-valid',
       ]
   ]
      )
   ?> 
<div class="form-row">
   <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['class'=>'t-inp'])->label(true); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Изменить'), ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-save']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>         
</div>
</div>
```

Вот action контроллера

```
public function actionUser($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

         $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');

        // only if user selected new image we want to save it in db
         if($model->imageFile){

             //save path to image in db
         $model->image = $model->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $model->imageFile->extension;
         };$model->save();

        // only if user selected new image we want to upload and save it on server
         if($model->imageFile) {

           //upload image on server

           $model->upload();
        }
        return $this->redirect(['user', 'id' => $model->id]);

        }else {
        return $this->render('user', [

            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
    }
```

Дело в том , что правила валидациии действуют , но сообщения об ошибках не появляются . В чем же дело?

Comment: Может в том что вы их не отображаете?

Comment: всмысле ? они разве автомматически не должны отображатся?

Comment: незнаю как в yii но во многих фреймворках приходиться самому выводить блок ошибок где не будь в header

Comment: в том то и дело , что блок с ошибками генерируется автоматически по каждым инпутом, но вот только ошибки туда почему-то не добавляются

Comment: а `id` у этих "нескольких форм" не совпадает случаем?

Comment: id разные , но конфликт все таки есть из-за чего-то . Когда оставил одну только форму - ошибки начали отображатся